# Filtering list with multi criterias

Tags: algorithm, filter

I have a class named Data; i have a list with some data and a function that filters this list with properties of data class

```
if a,b,c  filter words are not empty => data object must have these 3
if a,b are not empty => data object must have these 2
if a,c are not empty => data object must have these 2
if b,c are not empty => data object must have these 2
if a is not empty    => data object must have this
if b is not empty    => data object must have this
if c is not empty    => data object must have this
```

as you can see i wrote a code that fulfills its job but  i did not like my algorithm, so can you suggest me more smart algorithm because if field count of class increase i need to wrote new ifs.
(i am using java but i will not add java tag maybe there is a good pseudo code but javas functions are accepted too )

```
public class Data {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    private String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    private String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    private String getC() {
        return c;
    }


    private List<Data> filterData(List<Data> datas, String a, String b, String c) {
        List<Data> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Data data : datas) {
            if (a != null && data.getA().equals(a) && b != null && data.getB().equals(b) && c != null && data.getC().equals(c)) {
                result.add(data);
            } else if (a != null && data.getA().equals(a) && b != null && data.getB().equals(b)) {
                result.add(data);
            } else if (a != null && data.getA().equals(a) && c != null && data.getC().equals(c)) {
                result.add(data);
            } else if (b != null && data.getB().equals(b) && c != null && data.getC().equals(c)) {
                result.add(data);
            } else if (a != null && data.getA().equals(a)) {
                result.add(data);
            } else if (b != null && data.getB().equals(b)) {
                result.add(data);
            } else if (c != null && data.getC().equals(c)) {
                result.add(data);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

assume that you have cars list and Car class has color (a), model year (b), fuel type (c) assume that they are string not enum or you dont need to compare model year from its range

- if user wants white color, 2011 year, diesel , you have to add a car with these 3 property this means you cannot add white, 2012 ,diesel  because user wants 2011

  - user may want white,null,null then you just need to check only cars with white

Comment: Try Code Review

Comment: @Mitchel0022 Absolutely not. This is example code, that's off-topic at Code Review.

Comment: @Mitchel0022 i am not asking that is my code is good, i want to learn algorithm for this issue; you can assume that this code will work on e-commerce site for selling cars; User can filter cars with (km,color and price)  or (color and price) , i think there is a good algorithm for it.

Comment: your last 3 conditions already cover your first 4

Comment: @juvian if a is not null and b,c is null can you tell me which if condition will be true

Comment: a != null && data.getA().equals(a) would be true

Comment: @juvian so it will go in to 5th if -> last 3 condition works

Comment: Your current algorithm does not reflect what you explain at the beginning, will write an answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more generalized approach: add the strings you want to filter to an array, then add the values from data in same order. Then we can compare them in a more generalized way by using the fact that they will have the same indexes.

```
List<String> filterBy = new List<String>{a, b, c};
for (Data data : datas) {
    Boolean shouldAdd = true;
    List<String> values = new List<String>{data.getA(), data.getB(), data.getC()};
    for (Integer i = 0; i < filterBy.size(); i++) {
        if (filterBy[i] != null && filterBy[i].equals(values[i]) == false) {
            shouldAdd = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (shouldAdd) {
        result.add(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i need

Answer (score 1):

You can drastically reduce the number of `if` checks if you transform your condition. Currently, your condition (split up over 7 `if`checks), looks roughly like this:

```
(a & b & c) | (b & c) | (a & c) | (a & b) | a | b | c
```

Where each of `a`, `b` and `c` corresponds to `x != null && data.getX().equals(x)`

You can simplify this to just `a & b & c` if you change those components to `x == null || data.getX().equals(x)`, i.e. either the element is null, or it matches. You could also make this a separate method to make your code clearer. Also, you could replace the loop and `if` checks with `Stream.filter`

```
    private boolean matches(Object x, Object y) {
        return x == null || x.equals(y);
    }

    private List<Data> filterData(List<Data> datas, String a, String b, String c) {
        return datas.stream()
                .filter(d -> matches(a, d.getA()))
                .filter(d -> matches(b, d.getB()))
                .filter(d -> matches(c, d.getC()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Note: 1) I changed `data.getX().equals(x)` to `x.equals(data.getX())`, as you already know that `x` is `!= null` at this point, but `getX()` might be null. Also, your final `if` check, if all the filters are `null`, added `null` to the list, instead of `data`. I assumed this was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you INTEND the combination to be.  Though your description is ambiguous, and your existing code does not match it.  (As @juvian said, your last 3 conditions as currently written cover the first 4.)

```
private List<Data> filterData(List<Data> datas, String a, String b, String c) {
    List<Data> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Data data : datas) {
        if (! data.getA().equals(a == null ? data.getA() : a)) {
            // Filtered out
        }
        else if (! data.getB().equals(b == null ? data.getB() : b)) {
            // Filtered out
        }
        else if (! data.getC().equals(c == null ? data.getC() : c)) {
            // Filtered out
        }
        else {
            result.add(data);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: my intend : assume that you have cars list and car class has color (a), model year (b), fuel type (c) assume that they are string not enum
 if user wants white color, 2011 year, diesel , you have to add a car with these 3 property this means you cannot add white, 2012 ,diesel  because user wants 2011
user may want white,null,null then you just need to check only cars with white
(i will write this to my question because it looks like most of people did not understand my question)

Comment: @hkn I guessed right what your intent was, and that is what my code does. :-)